# regex php: "get rid [link1] get rid [link2] ... get rid" - problem 'getting rid' when there IS NO [link]

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

How to preg_replace() with a single line to achieve the following outputs?

```
$string1="get rid1 [link1] get rid2 [link2] ..."; // any number of links
echo "[<a href=link1>link1</a>][<a href=link2>link2</a>]";
$string2="get rid any text any text get rid"; // = no links: is a possibility
echo "";
```

I tried the following, which works for example $string1 but not for $string2 above:

```
$regex="/".
"[^\[\]]*". // the non-bracketed text before: -> eliminate
"\[(.*?)\]". // the bracketed text: [.]: -> convert into links 
"[^\[\]]*"; // get rid of non-bracketed text after: -> eliminate
"/";
echo preg_replace($regex,'<a href=jp.php?jp=\1>[\1]</a>',$string1);
```

I think non-capturing groups `(?:...)` might work, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: I'm getting confused by this "get rid".  Is it always "get rid"? Or can it be something else? It's unclear.

Comment: and you say it fails when there are no "[links]", well then there won't be any output... what's the fail?

Comment: 'get rid' could be any non-bracketed text, say "blah blah blah text blah text [link1] blah blah [linktextofanysort2] blah text blah". Any clearer now? - I've amended the original question, see above:...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just if?

```
if ($output = preg_replace($regex,'<a href=jp.php?jp=\1>[\1]</a>',$string1))
echo $output;
```

**Edit:** your regex won't work, preg_replace will replace ALL of the matched text so you would need to make the text before and after the link arguments too... Along the lines of:

```
preg_replace("(text we dont want to replace)(text we do want to replace)(more junk text)",$1." altered $2 = ".$2." ".$3, $string1)
```

.

```
$output = preg_replace($regex,'<a href=jp.php?jp=\1>[\1]</a>',$string1);
if ($output != $string1)
echo $output;
```

Comment: It does work! "rising sun (cf [幹]) + [乙]odd" becomes properly linked "[幹][乙]"

Comment: Yes but you want to replace only the link, this way it also deletes the text you don't want to affect...

Comment: ?? the output as my last comment is exactly how I want it, but I struggle with the empty output if there are no "[.]" constructs included....

Comment: Don't, empty output means no match, just use the if statemtent I gave in the first place.

Comment: Actually applying your first 'if' construct to $string1="needle + mouth > articulate" results in "needle + mouth > articulate" instead of an empty text.